# display result in a div after submitting in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a calculation function, whenever i put the the numbers in input field i want it to calculate the result when the  submit button is clicked and i also want it to show the result in a div.
now whenever i hit the button it displays the correct result in console, but i want to know how can i display the final result in a div inside a form with hooks?

the button :

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(solution)
  }
```

the form :

```
     <div onChange={(e) => setResult(solution)}>
      result : {setResult}
     </div>
```

Comment: I think you should add the complete code of your component. How is `handleSubmit` called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have specified your state like this:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState();
```

In this case you need to change your handler to update state whenever you get a result:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  //...
  setResult(solution)
  }
```

and render it in the div:

```
<div>
    result: {result}
</div>
```

**NOTE:** div element doens't have onChange event

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` doesn't have an `onChange`.  I think what you're trying to do is listen for changes in the solution.  The best way to do that is with `useState`. If you're keeping your solution in state with something like `const [result, setResult] = useState()`, the div will look more like:

```
<div>
  result : {result}
</div>
```

You just need to make sure you're updating the state correctly when the button is pressed. Maybe like:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  //... do calculation and assign it to solution variable
  setResult(solution)
  }
```